# Why does TinyMCE require typing something before being able to use the delete key properly?

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I have just implemented TinyMCE and it is working fine, except that the user must type something, even a space character, before being able to delete content.

Please tell me if you need more information.

Comment: Thanks for the responses! I have to take a detour for about a day and work on some more pressing stuff - but I will definitely try your answers out soon and get back.

Answer (score 0):

It's a browser bug. There is a hacky workaround I've seen and used in the past; I can't verify it at the moment. If you call the following once the TinyMCE editing iframe has loaded, it may work:

```
// doc is a reference to the iframe's document
try {
    doc.execCommand("Undo", false, false);
} catch (ex) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed it is a browser bug (almost FF). My workaround for this resets the design mode:

```
editor_instance = tinymce.EditorManager.getInstanceById(editor_id); //editor id needed here (ed.id)
editor_instance.getDoc().designMode = 'Off';
editor_instance.getDoc().designMode = 'On';
```